# How to make window absolute topmost?

Tags: windows, winapi, z-order, topmost

I use the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api to make my window topmost with the HWND_TOPMOST param.
It works fine, but still tooltips are on top of it.

[image: Example]

How to make my window on top of all. Is there an api that I'm missing?

**Edit:** I fixed it with a timer checking the foreground window and then setting mine to topmost.

Comment: You're simply supposed not to do that from an usability standpoint. Tooltips are, for the short time they are displayed, the most important thing the user wants to see, it's not acceptable that they are hidden by your window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to do that, as noted in the [Old New Thing blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/03/18/9485229.aspx). TopMost is TopMost. If two windows are competing one must loose. There is no secret MoreTopMost constant.