# How some applications overlap my WinForms app with TopMost

Tags: windows, winforms, topmost

I have the Win Forms application with active **TopMost** property. Everything works correctly (I cant overlap my app by the notepad and etc) but I have found that some applications launched before mine still overlap the app. For example, *Skype bubbling messages* and *Jing label* is located above my application. How is it realized? Is it possible to prevent them to be ahead of my app?
Thanks!

Comment: Something something [walls and ladders](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/17/10257351.aspx). Skype really wants their bubbles to be on top of everything, and you want your app to be on top of everything. Who wins?

Comment: The answer to this question gives all the detail by one of the greats who helped write Windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133603/how-to-make-window-absolute-topmost?rq=1

Comment: I understand that it is evil race, but still have the question how they have done it. It is timer that update TopMost property?
My app have to be like kiosk mode in order that a user can not cheat with data from Skype or other applications.